# mysql returns all rows with join with slash in value

Tags: mysql, sql

Why this query is returing all rows with `/` while using equal to in join

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE entity
(
id int(10) unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
parent_id int(10) unsigned,
title varchar(200),
path varchar(200),
primary key(id),
CONSTRAINT `SelfKey` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `entity` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
INSERT INTO entity (id, parent_id, title,path)
VALUES (1, null, 'parent title','1'),(2, 1, 'child 1','1/2'),
(3, 1, 'child 2','1/3')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select c.title,c.path from entity e inner join entity c on c.path = e.id
```

**Results**:

```
|   title        | path |
|----------------|------|
| parent title   |    1 |
| child 1        |  1/2 |
| child 2        |  1/3 |
```

I am thinking of using

```
select c.title,c.path from entity e inner join entity c on c.path = e.id
```

instead of

```
select c.title,c.path from entity e inner join entity c on c.path like concat(e.id,'/%')
```

the first one gives much better performence and also returns parent row along with children then the second one

Comment: What did you want it to return?

Comment: I know I can get children by querying `on c.path like concat(e.id,'/%')` just wanted to know here why its returing all rows while it should return only the parent ie. `path = 1`, is it escaping problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path is defined as a varchar and id is an integer.  MySQL will implicitly cast the varchar to an unsigned integer.  When it's converting 1/3 to an integer it will start at the left and read characters until it finds one that's not a digit (in this case /) and everything before that will be converted to an int.  Thus, 1/3 converts to 1:

```
select cast('1/3' as unsigned)

+ ---------------------------- +
| cast('1/3' as unsigned)      |
+ ---------------------------- +
| 1                            |
+ ---------------------------- +
```

See [MySQL Type Conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html)